# my way of solving this permutation question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many different ways can you distribute 3 apples, 3 oranges and 2 bananas to 8 children, if each child receives one fruit?

my work:
3 apples implies choosing 3 children from eight where the order of selection does not matter. That gives 8x7x6/3x2x1=56 options.

3 oranges the equals 3 choices from 5 where the order doesn't matter = 5x4x3/2x1=30 options.

And when we have distributed those, the remaining 2 children get the bananas - no further ootions.

Total possibilities = 56 x 30 = 1680 possibilities.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: in how many different ways can you distribute  3 apples, 3 oranges and 2 bananas to 8 children, if each child receives one fruit?

Comment: That's the "permutation question " which you answered yourself ! So what's the question :  Are you looking for another answer to this question or feedback on your solution ?

Comment: im asking if its correct

Comment: i re did the question again and got 560

Comment: Right the second time

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem when you calculate the number of ways you can distribute $3$ oranges among $5$ people. You calculate this as being

$$ \frac{5 \times 4 \times 3}{2 \times 1} = 30.$$

This is incorrect. The correct number of ways you can distribute $3$ oranges among $5$ people is 
$$ \frac{5\times 4 \times 3}{3 \times 2 \times 1} = 10$$

Combining this with the first part you did correctly we get the final answer $56 \times 10 = 560.$

Remember that in general the number of ways of choosing $k \leq n $ objects among $n$ is

$$ {n \choose k}:=\frac{n !}{k! (n-k)!}.$$

Comment: ok thanks,and do you mind helping me with one other question,it wouldnt let me post it here

Comment: If you want to ask another question you should make a new post.

Comment: ok im posting it right now